# Apply Filter and OrderBy on Access Form Simultaneously

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

#### Background

I am looking for a way to improve speed / performance of an Access 2007 form. Users have two different views of the data, each with different filtering and sorting criteria. I have a checkbox that toggles this option and have the code to handle the toggle event:

```
Private Sub FilterOpenJobs_Click()
    If (FilterOpenJobs.Value) Then
        Me.Filter = "Status='Open'"
        Me.OrderBy = "EndDate"
        Me.FilterOn = True
        Me.OrderByOn = True
    Else
        Me.Filter = ""
        Me.OrderBy = "JOB_NO"
        Me.FilterOn = False
        Me.OrderByOn = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem I have is that the form recordsource is fairly large, and applying the filters and sorts take some time. (Also note that the records come from mixed sources: some Access tables, some dBase tables.) It runs slowly enough that I am able to see the intermediate results between the `FilterOn` call and the `OrderByOn` call.

#### Questions

Is there anyway to apply a filter and sort simultaneously? Is there some way to lock the form from updating so that both can happen at once? Am I better off assigning a new value to the form `RecordSource` property? Would the form run faster if the filtering and ordering was done in the row source SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Is there anyway to apply a filter and sort simultaneously?*"

Yes, you touched on it with your third question.  Substitute a revised SQL SELECT statement as your form's `RecordSource`.  Then instead of one pause after the `Filter` assignment, and another after the `OrderBy`, you will have one pause which is of shorter duration than the sum of the other 2.

At least I hope it will be shorter.  It shouldn't take much effort to find out.

Changing the `RecordSource` automatically triggers a `Requery`, so be sure not to code an additional `Requery` at that point or the potential speed gain will vanish.

#### Code (added by asker)

Assuming the form recordsource property is an SQL SELECT statement (not a query name) without any where clauses or order by clauses:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.Tag = Me.RecordSource
    FilterOpenJobs_Click
End Sub

Private Sub FilterOpenJobs_Click()
    If (FilterOpenJobs.Value) Then
        Me.RecordSource = Replace(Me.Tag, ";", " WHERE Status='Open' ORDER BY EndDate;")
    Else
        Me.RecordSource = Replace(Me.Tag, ";", " ORDER BY JOB_NO DESC;")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well I had been looking for a way to use Filter and OrderBy on the form itself, but this way did end up being faster. If it's okay with you I will edit your answer to add the code I used to modify the RecordSource property in a 'smooth' manner.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to use the Application objects [Echo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff834500.aspx) property.  It prevents the ms access screen from being repainted during operations such as this.  One word of caution though, is that you MUST be sure to re-enable it in case of error.  Otherwise the application screen will not be responsive to anything.

```
Private Sub FilterOpenJobs_Click()

On Error GoTo handler:

    Application.Echo False, "Processing...."

    If (FilterOpenJobs.Value) Then
        Me.Filter = "Status='Open'"
        Me.OrderBy = "EndDate"
        Me.FilterOn = True
        Me.OrderByOn = True
    Else
        Me.Filter = ""
        Me.OrderBy = "JOB_NO"
        Me.FilterOn = False
        Me.OrderByOn = False
    End If

    Application.Echo True, ""
Exit Sub
handler:

    Application.Echo True, ""

    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can modify the `RecordSource` directly as HansUp suggested.